# Is there a .NET/C# mocking framework that doesn't require virtual methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, virtual

I'm trying to unit test a .NET web project with Visual Studio 2013's built-in tools. I have added Moq with NuGet, but can't test the controllers without rewriting the entire project with virtual methods and/or interfaces. So I am seeking a way to test the code without mucking about in the existing source code.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Hi! If you cannot rewrite the code, maybe you cannot do proper unit testing - I may be wrong, though. **Perhaps** *automatic exploration tests* might be useful in that situation. You can use Selenium with Firefox / IE / Chrome drivers. If you choose to do this, you can define some UI testing scenarios in your code and... run them. By the way, why would you test the web controllers ? Just asking... You may test the modules they depends on instead, though. Usually, the web controllers are dummy and lazy, they delegate the incoming requests to other, more hardworking modules :)

Comment: I had to mock the controller because its constructor depended on a repository that I did not want to alter in any way (so I mocked) - I suppose I could go back through and refactor all repositories to extend interfaces, but I am hoping to avoid that. I don't want to break anything

Comment: Then... just pass the controller a [dynamic object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) :) Or an *ExpandoObject*. Probably you can trick him (it) this way. The DynamicObject will act then as a fake repository. What do you think about this? Oops, only now I realize :( It won't work, sorry...

Comment: And... as a last resort... Define a dummy class having the same name as your repository, the same method signatures etc. and add some compilation flags here and there. When you want to test, those compilation flags will "comment out" the real implementation and use the dummy one. Though, this is a quite baaad solution.

Comment: 'Refactor / Extract Interface ...' is pretty easy now in Visual Studio, and it's built-in to the IDE.  How many interfaces would you need to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using VS2013 you can take advantage of Microsoft Fakes and Shims. More details and usage at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

Comment: I guess that is available only with the ultimate edition

Comment: Per http://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs it is available for Ultimate and Premium (whatever version this is) versions

Comment: I think Shims in Fakes framework is your option (obviously if you have the right license) but its not a good practice to use Shims for the code that you own. I would suggest you to eventually change your code to use interface/virtual methods.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps check out FakeItEasy: http://fakeiteasy.github.io/

Comment: Thanks for the idea; sadly, FakeItEasy also requires everything to be virtual or extended from an interface.

Comment: @eggshell OK, sorry then. I haven't actually used it but was reading about it the other day.

Answer (score 0):

The three current libraries able to do "elevated" mocking are:

- [JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx) ($399)
- [TypeMock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) (€399/yr)
- [Microsoft Fakes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) ($5999 - requires >>VS Enterprise<< omg)